# How to pass a line to the console in sublime text 2 editor

Tags: r, keyboard-shortcuts, sublimetext2

I use RStudio for working with R programming language and find the `ctrl+enter` shortcut to send a line to the console extremely useful in troubleshooting my work.

Now I am using sublimetext2 and I would like to do the same thing in RStudio, send a line to the console.

Is there a way to send the existing line to the console or a SublimeREPL console?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't know about the console, but this is possible with [SublimeREPL](https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL).

As long as you have a REPL and a file of the same language open at the same time, you can send a line (or a selection or file) to your open REPL via the SublimeREPL [Source Buffer Keys](http://sublimerepl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#source-buffer-keys). By default, `Ctrl+,` followed by `l` sends the current line to the REPL, but you can change the hotkey to `Ctrl+Enter` (in Python only, to protect other languages' default `Ctrl+Enter` functionality) by adding these lines to the top of your `Preferences -> Key Bindings – User` file:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+enter"], "command": "repl_transfer_current", "args": {"scope": "lines"}, "context":
    [
        { "key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "source.python", "match_all": true }
    ]
},
```

Other available scopes (from `Preferences -> Browse Packages -> SublimeREPL/Default (Windows).sublime-keymap`) are `selection`, `file`, and `block` (Clojure only). If you want to send a line to your REPL but **not** parse it immediately, you can add `"action":"view_write"` to the `args` object, like so:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+enter"], "command": "repl_transfer_current", "args": {"scope": "lines", "action": "view_write"}, "context":
    [
        { "key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "source.python", "match_all": true }
    ]
},
```

See the [Unofficial Sublime Text 2 Docs](https://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/key_bindings.html) for more information on key bindings.

In the case that the REPL is open in a different tab than your source (rather than a separate view), the source buffer hotkeys will **not** focus the REPL. I'm  sure it's possible to implement some sort of tab-swapping toggle key, but that sounds like a problem for another question.

Comment: That is terrific. Thank you @ProtractorNinja. A quick follow on question - is it possible to get both functions. So I'd like to send the line to the console and see it before it is executed. Thanks -- Sorry by console I mean REPL

Comment: @TahnoonPasha Yes! Add the second larger code snippet to your `Key Bindings – User` file alongside the first and adjust the `"keys"` value to whatever you want the send-but-don't-evaluate key to be, say, `ctrl+shift+enter`. Then `ctrl+enter` will send *and* evaluate the line, whereas `ctrl+shift+enter` will send and *not* evaluate the line. If you aren't interested in custom keypresses, the default send-but-don't-evaluate key combination is `ctrl+shift+,` followed by `l`.

Comment: Thanks @ProtractorNinja I think I must be doing something wrong. When I do the send-and-evaluate it doesn't echo in the REPL terminal, it just evaluates and returns an extra `>>>` when its done. What I was hoping was if I had e.g `import imaplib` and I did `ctrl+enter` I would see `>>>import imaplib` which would evaluate and then a new `>>>`. Is your code expected to have that effect? Thanks again for your help with this.

Comment: @TahnoonPasha Oh! My mistake; I misunderstood your request. I don't think that what you want is possible in SublimeREPL's current state—I looked at the source code and you'd probably have to write a command chaining plugin, even though what you want *seems* like a simple demand. Hopefully someone else can prove me wrong. Sorry I can't be of more help!

Comment: Thanks @ProtractorNinja, still incredibly useful to be able to send it line by line. Appreciate the help.

Comment: @ProtractorNinja, is it possible to make the cursor move to the next line in the source file upon executing Ctrl+Enter?

Comment: @Richard I'm not sure -- I stopped using Sublime Text long ago. Try looking at the keybinding docs I linked to above, and the [SublimeREPL](https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL) keybindings.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Do you mind if I asked what you switched to (always keeping an eye out for good tools)?

Comment: @Richard I use Vim these days.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to setting up your own key bindings, you can simply install `Enhanced-R`:

In Sublime:

- <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> (to bring up the command palette)
- type "`Install Package`"
- Navigate to `Enhanced-R`

If you are using Sublime for mostly just `R`, then you can set the default syntax for the whole app.  Or you can change it per file (<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> again, then start typing `Syntax Enhanced R`)

Then, like you are used to in RStudio, you simply hit <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd> to ship the code to the Console or R.app etc

Comment: With SublimeREPL I can open the R console within Sublime Text, is there a similar option for Enhanced-R?

Comment: @adibender you can use `sublimeREPL` and `Enhanced-R` simultaneously.   Personally, I've done away with `sublimeREPL` because it was getting annoying to deal with the window sizing.  I rather have two windows I can `CMD-tab` (or `CMD-\``) between

Comment: thx for the reply, but I couldn't quite get it to work. I can open R via SublimeREPL and I can send R-Code via Enhanced-R to the Rgui, but not send R-Code to SublimeREPL R-Console (via Enhanced-R short cuts). But I'll just post a question if I can't get it working after a couple more tries...

Comment: I haven't used sublimeREPL in ages, so I really dont know.  Have a look at the keybindings and the preferences. It is after all, all open source :)

Comment: hey @RicardoSaporta can I just ask, do you know by any chance how to get sublime send the code to the macOS terminal instead of the R gui? i tried to change the enhanced R package settings to `"App" : "Terminal"`, but it still opens and uses `R.app` whenever I hit cmd+enter. cheers

Comment: @FlorianOswald, that's peculiar and shouldn't happen.  Make sure you are using the latest version of ST3 & Enhanced R.  If it still is occurring, submit an issue at https://github.com/randy3k/Enhanced-R -- the developer is very responsive.

Comment: @RicardoSaporta blimey, i was using ST2. updated to ST3 and it works! that was a quick fix. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sending raw R code to SublimeREPL does work now:

1. Bring up the <kbd>Cmd/Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> menu
2. Select `R Application Switch`
3. Select `SublimeREPL`

When you have SublimeREPL active, you'll be able to send raw R to it with <kbd>Cmd/Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Note that by default, SublimeREPL won't display the code that gets sent in; it'll just show you the output. If you want to also see the code, you can change your user settings:

1. Navigate to `Preferences -> Package settings -> SublimeREPL -> Settings - User`
2. Turn on the `show_transferred_text` setting.

For example, if you don't have any other settings, your settings should look like this:

```
{
    "show_transferred_text": true
}
```